# How to prevent PowerShell's Measure-Object cmdlet from truncating your data?

Tags: powershell, measure-object

I am tryng to compare the following data to obtain the largest number:

```
$UserDeets 

name                 lastLogon
----                 ---------
Frank Ti 132273694413991065
Frank Ti 132279742884182029
Frank Ti 132282196073500496
Frank Ti 132272912975826719
Frank Ti 132282144707771693
Frank Ti 132228790551703041
```

To do this I am trying to use the built in 'measure' function. This is the code I am executing

```
($UserDeets| measure -Property lastLogon -Maximum ).Maximum
```

The results of this are as follows

```
1.322821960735E+17
```

As you can see althogh it is returning the correct data it is truncating the last few digits off.

Is there a way to prevent this truncation?

Comment: Interesting -- it appears that `Measure-Object` will produce a `Double` even if its input is `Int64`. This is more than a mere formatting problem, since a `Double` can't hold every value of an `Int64` precisely. Try `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Max([long[]]($userDeets.lastLogon))` (relying on LINQ rather than M-O).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's good to know the actual reason for this not working. I did find a work around.

Comment: You can convert your datetime and then get latest by sorting `@{Name="lastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have a solution to this. The answer is to not use 'measure'. This is a work around, but it gets the desired answer.

First i sorted the array:

```
$UserDeets = ($UserDeets | Sort-Object -Property LastLogon)
```

the highest object will be at the end of the array and can be obtained like this:

```
$UserDeets[-1]
```

Comment: A little more obvious than that would be `| Select -Last 1`.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) provided the crucial pointers in a comment on the question:

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.0, **[`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) invariably converts input numbers<sup>[1]</sup> for its `-Sum`, `-Maximum`, `-Minimum`, `-Average` and `-StandardDeviation` operations to `[double]` ([`System.Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Double)) and reports the result as that type, which can result in loss of precision.**

- [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) has reported this surprising behavior in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12103).

Your input numbers are of type `[long]`, and their values exceed the highest integer that can precisely be represented in a `[double]`, which is `9007199254740991` (you can calculate it with `[bigint]::pow(2, 53) - 1`)

**An efficient workaround is to use LINQ** ([`System.Linq.Enumerable.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Max)):

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Max(
  [long[]] $UserDeets.lastLogon
)
```

<sup>Note that the explicit `[long[]]` cast is needed in order for PowerShell to be able to call the generic `.Max()` method with a concrete type.</sup>

Another, **less efficient, but more PowerShell-idiomatic workaround** is to use *sorting*, similar to the [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60598924/45375):

```
# Sort the LastLogon property values, then grab the *last* one,
# which is the largest value.
($UserDeets.LastLogon | Sort-Object)[-1]
```

Sorting just the array of `.lastLogon` values rather than the full input objects minimizes the conceptually unnecessary overhead of creating a duplicate, sorted array just so the max. value can be determined.

---

<sup>[1] Note that for `-Min` and `-Max` *non-numeric* inputs are accepted too, as long as they implement the [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable) interface, in which case the inputs are preserved as-is and no loss of precision occurs; e.g., `'c', 'b', 'a' | Measure-Object -Minimum` and `[datetime]::now, [datetime]::now.AddDays(1) | Measure-Object -Maximum` work fine, because types `[string]` and `[datetime]` both implement `IComparable`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

i think you try get latest logon for users  by checking multiple DC, i do this by this code(where:`$samacc` - current user, `$controller` -lists of all DC hostnames.):

```
$scriptblock={
    param($samacc,$controller)
    $result=@()
    foreach($cont in $controller){
    $RESULT=$result + (Get-ADUser -Server $cont -Identity $samacc -Properties lastlogon,whenchanged,displayname,title,company  | sort-object lastLogon -descending | select-object enabled,displayname,samaccountname,title,company, @{Name="lastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}},whenchanged)
    }
    $result|Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastLogon|select -First 1
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.  Turn it back from 64-bit floating point to 64-bit integer.  But some numbers will be slightly off (.000000000000005 or 5/1 quadrillion % error), or 6 ten millionths of a second (ticks) if it were a datetime.

```
$jsontext = @'
[ { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132273694413991065 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132279742884182029 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132282196073500496 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132272912975826719 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132282144707771693 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132228790551703041 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon: 132282196073500499 },
  { name: 'Frank Ti', lastLogon:   9007199254740991 } ]
'@

$userdeets = $jsontext | convertfrom-json
[long]($userdeets | measure lastlogon -Maximum).maximum

132282196073500496
```

Comment: It works for this particular value, but that's getting lucky. Had the maximum value been `132282196073500497`, `Measure-Object` would not be able to produce it since that value can't be represented with sufficient precision in a `double`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right.  I thought if it was long before the conversion powershell might keep the precision.  It stays at 132282196073500496.

Comment: @JeroenMostert How did you get that number?

Comment: I took 132282196073500496 from the question and added 1. :-) No magic involved; the fact that small differences will fail to be represented correctly is a simple consequence of how floating-point works. That 132282196073500496 is exactly representable I did not know, but is a happy coincidence (132272912975826719 is not, for example). The next number that can be represented exactly is 132282196073500512. The difference between these is 16, which is of course not coincidentally a power of 2.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh I see, I thought it was a max number.

Comment: The max. safe integer you can represent in a `[double]` is `9007199254740991`, which you can calculate with `[bigint]::pow(2, 53) - 1`. As @Jeroen points out, your solution will result in a loss of precision.